# Application mistakenly published

Tags: android, google-play

Currently I am making a small application, this is not at all complete and so far the publications were by alpha tab. the problem is that accidentally went up one tab apk production and now do not know how to remove it, for now I have the unpublished application. but then how I can fix this problem and keep using.

need to continue to publish only versions for the community where the testers are not to appear publicly in the play store.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an app is published, you cannot switch back to only alpha/beta testing - unpublishing the app disables all release channels.

You can certainly push a new release version that serves as a placeholder (i.e., sign up to be notified or just a coming soon notice) and then continue to beta test (assuring that you update the beta test's build number higher than the placeholder release version).